# Sorting arraylist and returning an arraylist (not a list) - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to display sorted information using a `RecyclerView`. To do so, I've got an `ArrayList` of custom datatype. I want to sort the data in the `ArrayList` by descending order, using one of the fields in the `ArrayList`. I'm familiar with the methods that are already available (`sortWith`, `sortBy`, `sortByDescending`, etc) but unfortunately, they all change from `ArrayList` to `List` and this stops the recycler view from working. Ideally, I'd like to preserve the `ArrayList` because I need it for other processes that I carry out later in the project.

WHAT I'M TRYING TO ACHIEVE:

INPUT: `arrayListName = ArrayList<CustomType>`

PROCESS: [sort by decending order of `arrayListName.firstName`]

OUTPUT: `return ArrayList<CustomType>`

I've tried casting the `List` (shown below) to `ArrayList`, but that throws the below error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Line of code that throws the error (I've tried various methods, but they all throw an exception on that line):

```
val sortedModel = model.sortedWith(compareBy { it.name}) as ArrayList<Model>
```

Any help is appreciated(:

***I'm happy with a java solution too because I understand it and can easily implement from java to kotlin.***

Comment: It'd be pretty easy to help you, honestly, if we had the code you were using that produced that error.

Comment: Make sure import types are matching, `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`, vs `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: @LouisWasserman i've added the line of code towards the very end (:

Comment: @GayanWeerakutti I don't actually import anything.. should I be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not cast a `List` to an `ArrayList` directly. If you want to convert a `List` to `ArrayList`, you can do it this way:

```kotlin
val sortedModel = model.sortedByDescending { it.name }.toCollection(ArrayList())
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
val list = arrayList.sortedByDescending { it.firstName.length }
        result.addAll(list)
```

Full code:

```
val arrayList: ArrayList<CustomType> = arrayListOf()
val result: ArrayList<CustomType> = arrayListOf()
arrayList.add(CustomType("Aadddd"))
arrayList.add(CustomType("Ccd"))
arrayList.add(CustomType("Bbdd"))
arrayList.add(CustomType("Ffddd"))
arrayList.add(CustomType("Dd"))

val list = arrayList.sortedByDescending { it.firstName.length }
result.addAll(list)
```

**Output:**

`SORT [{"firstName":"Aadddd"},{"firstName":"Ffddd"},{"firstName":"Bbdd"},{"firstName":"Ccd"},{"firstName":"Dd"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sortWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-with.html#sortwith) instead it does inplace , try this

```
data class A(
    val x : Int
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var a = arrayListOf( A(1) ,A(2) ,A(3) ,A(4) )
    a.sortWith(compareByDescending { it.x })
    assert( a is ArrayList )
    println(a)
}
```

[try yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/lxBm74ZVq)